# Support for CORS with IBM Integration Bus (Message Broker)

Tags: cors, esb, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

How can you configure IIB to support CORS, and the preflight request?

I would like to configure IIB as a REST proxy with support for CORS.  I have IIB configured with an HTTP Input node and my suspicion is that it is rejecting my browser's preflight request, which uses the OPTIONS header.

I have successfully tested browser and server with CORS enabled, without IIB.  I have disabled Security in my browser and routed requests through IIB to verify that my IIB flow works.  When I re-enable browser security, I get the following error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".  I added a breakpoint right after the HTTP Input node in IIB, but the OPTIONS request never makes it to it.

Comment: IBM: "OPTIONS is not yet supported by IIB."

Comment: CORS support is in IBM Integration Bus Version 10. See this article for a description of how to enable/use it: https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2015/06/05/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-ibm-integration-bus-v10/

Answer (score 0):

Part of a possible solution is described here: [How to define CORS in Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile V8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277953/how-to-define-cors-in-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile-v8-5)

Basically, I installed the IBM-supplied proxyservlet.war in WAS and configured it to use the filter described in the above link. The war file is with the installation files for WMB in the tools folder. I had to customize the servlet initialization parameters to use my WMB broker. There were about 3 parms that had to be configured. When you call WMB through the HttpConnector directly the default port is 7080. When you go through the proxy servlet the default port is 9080. So you will use 9080 and the CORSFilter class in the proxy servlet will handle the CORS preflight request.

The proxyservlet.war is described in the IBM documentation for WMB Information Center.